# Modify object from multiple async streams in Dart

Tags: multithreading, dart, concurrency, stream

Imagine we had a object like this

```
class Foo {
  List<int> data = [];

  void addAndCheck(int n){
    for(int number in data){
        // check something
    }
    data.add(n);
  }
}
```

and the imagine we spawn a bunch of subscriptions like this

```
Foo foo = Foo();

for(int i = 0; i++; i<10){
  subscriptions.add(api.someRandomStream().listen((response){
    foo.addAndCheck(response.value);
  }));
}
```

As it stands, if this code is run it might work but as soon as the streams start emitting around the same time we get a exception: `Concurrent modification during iteration`

The cause is the for loop, but how can this problem be solved? In a language like Java there are things like ConcurrentHashMap, Collections.synchronizedList(...), etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get a concurrent modification error during the iteration, then you are doing something *asynchronous* inside the loop. That is, your function is probably `async` and there is at least one `await` inside the loop. That will allow another event to trigger while you are awaiting, and then modify the list.

There are several ways to avoid the exception, all with different trade-offs:

1. Don't do anything asynchronous in the loop, and make sure that nothing you do in there will call `addAndCheck` again. Then there should be no problem because the loop will complete before anyone else has a chance to modify the list. That obviously only works if you don't *need* to do something asynchronous.
2. Copy the list. If you do `for(int number in [...data]) { ... }` (or `in data.toList()` as it used to be written), then the list that you iterate is a different list than the one which is modified. It also means that you might not have checked all the elements that are actually in the list at the point you reach the `add` call.
3. Don't use an iterator. If you do `for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { var number = data[i]; ... }` instead, you will not get a concurrent modification error from the iterator. If elements are added at the end of the list, then you will eventually reach them, and all is well. If elements are *removed* from the list, or added in any place other than at the end, then you might be skipping elements or seeing some of them twice, which may be bad for you.
4. Use a mutex. If you want to be sure that all the tests on existing elements are performed before any other element is added, then you need to prevent anything from happening while you are adding. Assume a `Mutex` class of some sort, which would allow you to write code like:

   ```
   class Foo {
     List<int> data = [];
     final _mutex = Mutex();  

     void addAndCheck(int n) async {
       await _mutex.acquire();
       for(int number in data){
         // check something
       }
       data.add(n); 
       _mutex.release();
     }
   }
   ```

   (I found [`package:mutex`](https://pub.dev/packages/mutex) by searching, I have no experience with it).
   This might slow down your code, though, making every operation wait for the previous one to complete entirely.

In the end, only you can say which trade-off is best for the behavior of your code.